# Unable to navigate to the right screen after registering during registration flow

Tags: react-native, react-native-navigation

I have a registration flow for my application. The registration flow goes like this:

Landing page -> registration -> ChooseAvatar -> Friend -> Home

The problem starts with the fact that I need to be logged in to add friends, so the user is registered to my database when they press the continue button on the ChooseAvatar screen.

The Friend screen is accessible by logged in users only, but I need it to render different content if the user is in the registration flow or not. To support this I created a state variable in my AuthContext - inRegistrationFlow which is set to true upon entering the registration flow and should be set to false when they press the button to navigate to the Home screen.

I think something is happening with the way my state is updating because right now I am automatically redirected to my Home screen as soon as the user registers.

```
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Stack.Navigator>
        {isLoggedIn ? (
          <Stack.Group>
            <Stack.Screen name="Navbar" component={Navbar} options={{headerShown: false}} />
            <Stack.Screen name="Restaurant" component={Restaurant} options={{headerShown: false}} />
            <Stack.Screen name="Review" component={Review} options={{headerShown: false}} />
          </Stack.Group>
        ) : (
          <Stack.Group>
            <Stack.Screen name="LandingPage" component={LandingPage} options={{ headerShown: false }}/>
            <Stack.Screen name="Register" component={Register} options={{ header: () => <Header /> }}/>
            <Stack.Screen name="ChooseAvatar" component={ChooseAvatar} options={{ header: () => <Header /> }}/>
            <Stack.Screen name="Friend" component={Friend} options={{ header: () => <Header /> }}/>
            <Stack.Screen name="Login" component={Login} options={{ header: () => <Header />  }}/>
          </Stack.Group>
        )}
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
};
```

Here is my Navbar component for reference. The Friend route is included in here.

```
        <Tab.Navigator
        screenOptions={{
            tabBarActiveTintColor: '#739072',
            tabBarStyle: { display: keyboardVisible ? 'none' : 'flex', height: 50, backgroundColor: '#F5F5F5', borderTopWidth: 1, borderTopColor: 'gray' },
        }}
    >
        <Tab.Screen name="GlobalStack" component={GlobalStack} options={{ tabBarButton: () => null, headerShown: false }} />
        <Tab.Screen
            name="Home"
            component={Home}
            options={{
            tabBarIcon: ({color, size}) => (
                <Icon name="home" color={color} size={size}/>
            ),
            tabBarLabel: () => null,
            headerShown: false,
            headerTitle: ''
            }}
        />
        <Tab.Screen
            name="Friend"
            component={Friend}
            options={{
            tabBarIcon: ({color, size}) => (
                <AntDesign name="addusergroup" color={color} size={size}/>
            ),
            tabBarLabel: () => null,
            headerShown: inRegistrationFlow,
            header: inRegistrationFlow ? () => <Header /> : undefined
            }}
        />
        <Tab.Screen
            name="SearchRestaurant"
            component={SearchRestaurant}
            options={{
            tabBarIcon: ({color, size}) => (
                <Material name="restaurant-outline" color={color} size={size}/>
            ),
            tabBarLabel: () => null,
            headerShown: false
            }}
        />
    </Tab.Navigator>
```

I tried a lot of different things. I tried to put a callback function in my handleCompleteRegistration function to pass to registerUser in the AuthContext:

```
 const handleCompleteRegistration = async () => {
    const navigateToFriend = () => {
      navigation.navigate("Friend");
    };
    if (!selectedAvatar) {
      alert("Please select an avatar");
      setLoading(false);
      return;
    }
    setLoading(true);
    const completedUserDetails = {
      ...formData,
      profile_picture: selectedAvatar,
    };
      try {
        console.log("Completed user details:", completedUserDetails);
        await registerUser(completedUserDetails, navigateToFriend);
      } catch (error) {
        console.error("Error completing registration:", error);
      } finally {
        setLoading(false);
      }
    };
```

I was hoping that it would navigate to Friend before setting loading to false but that didnt work.

I also tried adding a useEffect that would navigate to Friend when the conditions were met:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    const navigateIfReady = async () => {
      const isNewUser = await AsyncStorage.getItem("isNewUser");
      if (isNewUser === "true" && isLoggedIn) {
        navigation.navigate("Friend");
        console.log("Navigating to Friend screen")
        await AsyncStorage.removeItem("isNewUser");
      }
    };
    navigateIfReady();
  }, [isLoggedIn, navigation, route.params]);
```

My hope here was that once the login status changed it would navigate me to Friend but still no matter what I've done I'm navigated to Home after registering my user.

Comment: When isLoggedIn is set to true Navbar route is rendered and Friend route is not anymore available.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I forgot to add that the Friend route is available in the Navbar component. I'll try adding it though just incase.